# Why is any norm-bounded family on a reﬂexive Banach space relatively weakly compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is any norm-bounded family $T \subseteq L(X)$ on a reﬂexive Banach space $X$ relatively weakly compact?

Comment: Why do you assume that this might be true?

Comment: Did you mean a norm-bounded family in the dual?

Comment: @DanielFischer no

Comment: @Rasmus Lemma 2.7 page 312 One parameter Semigroups For Linear Evolution Equation.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "relatively weakly compact"? Relatively compact in the topology of pointwise convergence as maps to $\sigma(X,X')$?

Comment: For a set of operators T ⊂ L(X), X a Banach space, the
following assertions are equivalent.

(a) T is relatively compact in Lσ(X).

(b) {T x : T ∈ T } is relatively weakly compact in X for all x ∈ X.

(c) T is bounded, and {T x : T ∈ T } is relatively weakly compact in X for all x in some dense
subset of X.

Lσ(X) the space L(X) endowed with the weak operator topology

Answer (score 1):

Recall $L(X,Y')\cong_1 (Y\otimes_{\pi} X)'$ via cononical isometric isomorphism 
$I_{X,Y}$ well defined by $I_{X,Y}(T)(y\otimes_\pi x)=(T(x))(y)$. Since $X=X''$ we conclude
$$
L(X)\cong_1 (X'\otimes_{\pi} X)'
$$ 
As $I_{X,X'}$ is isometric isomorphism, then the family $\mathcal{S}:=I_{X,X'}(\mathcal{T})\subset (X'\otimes_{\pi} X)'$ is norm bounded, hence $\operatorname{cl}_{w^*}(\mathcal{S})$ is $w^*$-compact. Since  $L^\sigma(X)\cong((X'\otimes_{\pi} X)',w^*)$ via $I_{X,X'}$, then $\operatorname{cl}_{L^\sigma(X)}(\mathcal{T})=I_{X,X'}^{-1}(\operatorname{cl}_{w^*}(\mathcal{S}))$ is compact in $L^\sigma(X)$. Thus $\mathcal{T}$ is a relatively weakly compact family.